# My recursive function in plsql doesn't work inside procedure

Tags: oracle, recursion, plsql

I was just learning plsql .. I've created function that will returning day which is not holiday recursively (it'll searching next day that is not holiday) from given parameter "THEDAY" , but it doesn't work . i wonder why it still returning holiday.

```
  FUNCTION WEEKDAY(THEDAY IN OUT DATE)
    RETURN DATE
  IS
    count_row number;
    nextday DATE;
    isholiday boolean;   
  BEGIN
    nextday := THEDAY;
    isholiday := false;
    IF (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(THEDAY),'DY','nls_date_language=american')='SAT') THEN
      nextday := THEDAY + 2;
      isholiday := true;
    ELSIF((TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(THEDAY),'DY','nls_date_language=american')='SUN') ) THEN
      nextday := THEDAY +1;
      isholiday := true;                        
    ELSE
      BEGIN
        SELECT count(*)
        INTO count_row
        FROM TBL_MSTHOLIDAYS
        WHERE trunc(DDAY) = trunc(THEDAY);

        IF count_row <> 0 THEN
          nextday := THEDAY+1;
          isholiday := true;
        END IF;

  END;
    END IF;

    if (isholiday = true) THEN
      RETURN WEEKDAY(nextday);
    ELSE 
      RETURN THEDAY;
    END IF;

  END;
```

Comment: why is a `theday` declared as `OUT` parameter?

Comment: As hotfix wrote: Remove the `OUT` it's not used here. The Function works as intended. Have a look at your `TBL_MSTHOLIDAYS`.

Comment: Ideally we don't use `OUT` parameter in a Function as by nature a `Function` should always return a value. So defining a `OUT` parameter is redundant. Nevertheless, its not restricted for a function not to have a `OUT` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

My Bad ...

As [kara](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4340461/kara) said the function works as intended , i got the wrong output because it calculated in the next condition ...

and for OUT parameter i already remove it, Thank you